# mod_rewrite: redirect two domain request on same server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a wordpress multisite setup where multiple domain are rooting to the same path and then wordpress decides which content will be displayed.

i have to old pages, which need a redirect to the new page. But the problem is, that both pages have the same path structure:

old page:

```
www.schlangenbader-hof.de/arrangements/wellnessschnaeppchen/
```

new page:

```
www.schlangenbader-hof.de/de/arrangement/kurzurlaub-wellness-schnaeppchen-im-rheingau-massage-im-wellnessbereich-vita-nova-3-tage-entspannung-pur-im-3-sterne-hotel-schlangenbader-hof/
```

old page:

```
www.soodener-hof.de/arrangements/wellnessschnaeppchen/
```

new page:

```
www.soodener-hof.de/de/arrangement/kurzurlaub-2-naechte-im-werratal-wellness-und-erholung-im-waldhotel-soodener-hof/
```

if i use a pattern like this:

```
RewriteRule ^arrangements/wellnessschnaeppchen/ de/arrangement/kurzurlaub-2-naechte-im-werratal-wellness-und-erholung-im-waldhotel-soodener-hof/ [R=301,NC,L]
```

then this would work for one page only. but how to address both url requests and redirect them properly? i did not find anything via google.

Comment: As far as I can see, these two URL address have nothing in common, for except the word "arrangement"(s).
You cannot use one universal rule for this kind of situation.
Look at RewriteMap, but if this only 2 url it not worth.

Comment: yes exactly. thats the problem. the new urls are different. so i need to RewriteCondition?!